# How can we extract covariance matrix from a parsnip object?

Tags: r, tidymodels, r-parsnip

I am trying to use tidymodels ecosystem to perform econometric analysis. The example I am following at the moment is from the book **“Principles of Econometrics with R”** by *Colonescu*. The data from the book can be downloaded through

```
devtools::install_github("ccolonescue/PoEData")
```

**0.1 The Example**

I am creating a wage discrimination model, which has interaction effects as well. The model is as follows

```
library(tidymodels)
library(PoEdata)#to load the data
library(car)#For linearHypothesis function
```

### Loading required package: carData

```
lm_model <- linear_reg() %>% 
     set_engine("lm")#model specification
data("cps4_small")
mod1 <- lm_model %>% 
     fit(wage~educ+black*female, data=cps4_small)#model fitting
```

**0.2 The Issue**

After creating the model, I want to test the hypothesis that there is no discrimination on the basis of gender or race. In other words, I need to test the hypothesis that the coefficients of black, female, and black:female are all zero at the same type. I want to use `linearHypothesis` function from the car package for this.

```
hyp <- c("black=0", "female=0", "black:female=0")
tab <- tidy(linearHypothesis(mod1, hyp))
```

This gives me an error that `there is no applicable method for vcov for an object of class _lm or model_fit`.

So, can someone help me how I can generate covariance matrix from a parsnip object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the `extract_fit_engine()` to get out the underlying `lm` fit object from the `parsnip` model object.

```r
library(tidymodels)
library(PoEdata)
library(car)

data("cps4_small")

lm_model <- linear_reg() %>% 
  set_engine("lm")

mod1 <- lm_model %>% 
  fit(wage ~ educ + black * female, data = cps4_small)

hyp <- c("black=0", "female=0", "black:female=0")

mod1 %>%
  extract_fit_engine() %>%
  linearHypothesis(hyp) %>%
  tidy()
#> # A tibble: 2 × 6
#>   res.df     rss    df sumsq statistic  p.value
#>    <dbl>   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>     <dbl>    <dbl>
#> 1    998 135771.    NA   NA       NA   NA      
#> 2    995 130195.     3 5576.      14.2  4.53e-9
```

<sup>Created on 2021-11-13 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Thank you for your support, @EmilHvitfeldt. It was quite helpful. I have used your package "paletteer". Thanks for the package as well.